# Modeling an activity feed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, database-design, data-modeling

I would like a second opinion on an activity feed I'm trying to model. I've come up with three ways.

I have a Project, Membership, Bucket, Upload, and Document models, all are ActiveRecord models. A Project has many memberships and many buckets. A bucket has many uploads, and an upload has many documents. I would like to track activity on memberships, buckets, uploads, and documents (updates, deletions, creations, etc...).

```
class Project
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :buckets
  has_many :documents, through: :buckets
end

class Bucket
  belongs_to :project
  has_many :uploads
  has_many :documents, through: :uploads
end

class Upload
  belongs_to :bucket
  has_many :documents
end

class Document
  belongs_to :upload
end
```

This is fairly easy in itself. But some buckets are private, and only visible to admins. This means that their activities, and activities on their uploads and their documents can only be visible to admins.

### Approach 1: A polymorphic Activity class

Activity would belong to a trackable object, in this case `Membership`, `Document`, `Upload`, and `Bucket`.

```
class Activity
  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :trackable, polymorphic: true
end
```

This lets me do things like `@project.activities`. To solve the privacy issue, I can use scopes.

```
scope :public, -> { joins(:trackable).where(trackable: { private: false }) }
```

But only Bucket objects, and by extension their Upload and their Document objects have a privacy flag. Membership does not. I must add privacy flag to all trackable models just so that they can speak to the same interface.

```
class Membership
  def private; false; end
end

class Upload
  delegate :private, to: :project
end

class Document
  delegate :private, to: :upload
end
```

Then I can do this in some policy object.

```
@activities = if current_user.admin?
  @project.activities
else
  @project.activities.public
end
```

### Approach 2: Add a private flag on activities

I can add a privacy flag on Activity.

```
@bucket.activities.build(project: @project) do |a|
  a.private = @bucket.private?
end
```

Then I can do this in some policy object.

```
@activities = if current_user.admin?
  @project.activities
else
  @project.activities.public
end
```

This is easy, but not flexible. If we add an accesses table to buckets, so that their visibility is now based on access rather than user role, we would have to refactor painfully.

Are there better ways to model this feed? How would you do it? I can't use any gems like public activity, so please do not suggest them.

Answer (score 2):

I think your first approach is by far better, the only thing I might do nicer is:

```
class Activity
  scope :auth_with, -> (auth) { joins(:trackable).where(trackable: { private: trackable_access(auth) }) }

  class << self
  private
    def trackable_access(auth)
      return false unless auth
      auth.admin?
    end
  end
end
```

Then you could call a pretty

```
@project.activities.auth_with(current_user)
```

and not be concerned with access issues, also your access logic will be in one place only, and the only place it concerns - `Activity`, so changing access logic will boil down to replacing `auth.admin?` in `trackable_access` with any other type of authentication.

The cherry on top is making `trackable_access` private, so you can't call `Activity.trackable_access(...)` without evals.

This is of course only my take on the matter, but I hope I helped somehow :)

Comment: Thanks. Can you tell me what you think? Fundamentally there are two types of activities: Workspace and Bucket ones. Workspace activities are public. They include memberships. Bucket activities are private or public, depending on the bucket. They include uploads, documents, and comments. The feed can be made up of both. This makes retrieving bucket activity easy: If user is an admin, grab all activities for buckets in the current workspace, otherwise grab all activities that belong to public buckets. We combine them with workspace activities. What do you think?

Comment: In addition, one attractive thing about the individual feeds is that I can have an isolated feed per bucket if I need to. That would include activities on documents and uploads, and comments on documents that belong to a single bucket.

Comment: I'm also concerned about the performance implications of the first approach.

Comment: I think this approach is understandable and reasonable. If you keep your auth logic separated and internal it should be nice and clean.

Comment: I think I'll go down a different route. I will create a joined table that maps an activity to a user. Using a background job I will create a mapping in that table if the user has access to the activity. I don't know how scalable that is, but it doesn't seem bad. If I have 50 people in one project, I would have to add 50 mappings, but its idempotent, and solves the question of permissions. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31186928/is-this-a-scalable-way-to-build-a-feed

Answer (score 1):

I would honestly combine both approaches.  The second approach gets to what you really want your data to reflect - Is this activity private or not?

I would then probably have the `:private` field on `Activity` set in a `before_save` hook, with the logic of something like "set this to private if I belong to a private `Bucket`".

I prefer this approach because if your logic for what makes an `Activity` private every changes, or if you need to add flags for other types of access (e.g. `viewable_to_managers`), you can add a similar hook and run a script to update all of the past `Activity` objects.

Comment: Thanks for chipping in. Can you read my comment to Piotr Kruczek's answer and tell me what you think?

Comment: If you're concerned about performance, then certainly having a field in the database on the Activites table is going to allow for a faster query than having to do a join just to understand whether or not something is meant to be included.